# Issue with XmlJavaTypeAdapter AndJava XML Client Module of Enunciate

Tags: java, jaxb, junit4, enunciate

1. Created `DateFormatterAdapter` class and applied to `date` field

   ```
   @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
   public class Event {
       @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateFormatterAdapter.class)
       private Date date;

       private String description;


       public Date getDate() {
           return date;
       }

       public void setDate(final Date date) {
           this.date = date;
       }

   }  

   private static class DateFormatterAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {
       private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy");

       @Override
       public Date unmarshal(final String v) throws Exception {
           return dateFormat.parse(v);
       }

       @Override
       public String marshal(final Date v) throws Exception {
           return dateFormat.format(v);
       }
   }
   ```
2. `EventService` is having one method  which is using an object of `Event` as input

   ```
   public class EventService {

        public void findEvent(Event  event) {

        }

   }
   ```
3. Also we added enunciate 2.10.1 configurations along with Java XML Client Module in the pom.xml
   https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki/Module-Java-XML-Client
4. We have an integration test class  which is testing `findEvent` method in `EventService` .But fails with compilation error after adding enunciate configurations.  Before it was working fine

   ```
     @Test
     public void testFindEvent{
         Event event= new Event();

         event.setDate(new Date());

         EventService  service=new EventService();
         service.findEvent(event);
     }
   ```

   But after running `mvn test`, we got Compilation error in  `event.setDate(new Date());`

   > method setDate in class Event cannot be applied to given types;
   >           [ERROR] required: java.lang.String
   >           [ERROR] found: java.util.Date

Comment: Your class `DateFormatterAdapter` is `private`, which makes it inaccessble to JAXB. Make it `public` instead. Also, the date format string is wrong - `mm` is **minutes**. You need to use `MM` for months. But even better: You don't need this adapter at all. Use JAXB's standard binding and the standard ISO-8601 date format.

Comment: Also, the compilation error is strange. It means that the field in your class `Event` is a `String` instead of a `Date`, which does not correspond with the code that you posted.

Comment: Thanks  Jesper . Yes, 'mm' was a mistake in my post and I updated to 'MM'. Regarding your second, "the compilation error is strange" ,our field is of date type, but after adding enunciate , our tests were failing